# How many data types are there in JavaScript, what are they, and what is considered a type?

Tags: javascript, types

I'm curious how many types there are in JS, because I have read conflicting answers from otherwise reliable sources:

**If we look at the [ECMAScript spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values), there are 8 types:**

- Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, BigInt, and Object

It seems `function` is counted as object.

---

**If we look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), they say there is 9 types:**

Six Data Types that are primitives, checked by typeof operator:

1. undefined : typeof instance === "undefined"
2. Boolean : typeof instance === "boolean"
3. Number : typeof instance === "number"
4. String : typeof instance === "string"
5. BigInt : typeof instance === "bigint"
6. Symbol : typeof instance === "symbol"

Structural Types:

7. Object : typeof instance === "object". Special non-data but Structural type for any constructed object instance also used as data structures: new Object, new Array, new Map, new Set, new WeakMap, new WeakSet, new Date and almost everything made with new keyword;
8. Function : a non-data structure, though it also answers for typeof operator: typeof instance === "function". This is merely a special shorthand for Functions, though every Function constructor is derived from Object constructor.

Structural Root Primitive:

9. null : typeof instance === "object". Special primitive type having additional usage for its value: if object is not inherited, then null is shown;

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: I think you're looking for opinions here, which isn't really what stack overflow is for. That said, I'd lean towards the spec over mdn.

Comment: Update your spec link: https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values . There are 8 of them.

Comment: Your last 3 Structural Types in MDN are all of type "object", so it's total goes back to 7, that is how much different values `typeof` can return (as `function` is also "object")

Comment: @georg thanks, but what about function? Is it a type?

Comment: @ZiiMakc: nope, function is an object.

Comment: @georg `typeof (function () {})` yields `"function"` though..

Comment: @georg so we should stick to spec and answer 8?

Comment: @ZiiMakc: yes, that's correct.

Comment: Are you ready for this? String is an object. Integer is also an object in JavaScript. When you set `var i = 10`, you can right after convert it - for example - to string, using its `toString()` function.`

Comment: @CallumMorrisson: what `typeof` returns is not necessarily the actual type, see the table here https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-typeof-operator

Comment: @Gil: that's not true. strings are not objects and neither are numbers.

Comment: @Gil Everything in JS is derived from `Object` but that doesn’t mean everything is an Object. `(() => {}) instanceof Object` is true but `1 instanceof Object` is false. So, we can say function is of object type while *number*  and *staring* are not. While *Number* and *String* are object as `Number instanceof Object` is true.

Comment: @georg Not by itself, no. :) Note that I wrote "an object in _JavaScript_". When you set an int, JavaScript uses [a primitive wrapper object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript) to handle it. When you work with it you actually work with the wrapper.

Comment: `null` isn’t structural. `typeof null` is considered an unfixable bug. _“if object is not inherited, then null is shown”_ — that’s not the only use for `null` and this property is somewhat arbitrary. See [this 2ality article](https://2ality.com/2021/01/undefined-null-revisited.html) about the different usages of `null` vs. `undefined`. _Null_ itself is still its own type, though.

Comment: @Gil When accessing properties from primitives, they are _coerced to objects_ (an operation which can be optimized by the engine). But the values themselves are still primitives: they are immutable and self-identifying (i.e. the value is identified by the value itself as opposed to, say, a reference to the value) values; `"" instanceof Object` is `false`, as already mentioned; and `Object(str) !== str` for any string `str`; same for numbers. [This answer](/a/9109037/4642212), where you probably got this idea from, is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current edition of the ECMAScript spec defines 8 value types:

1. Undefined
2. Null
3. Boolean
4. String
5. Symbol
6. Number
7. BigInt
8. Object

https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types

The `typeof` operator is a big source of confusion in JavaScript, because what it returns is not *always* the actual type of the value. The conversion table for typeof (https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-typeof-operator) is like this

| Type of val | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Undefined | `undefined` |
| Null | `object` **!!!** |
| Boolean | `boolean` |
| Number | `number` |
| String | `string` |
| Symbol | `symbol` |
| BigInt | `bigint` |
| Object (does not implement [[Call]]) | `object` |
| Object (implements [[Call]]) | `function` **!!!** |

Note the two exceptions marked with `!!!`

To confuse us further, the language also provides wrapper functions for these 4 primitive types

1. Boolean
2. Number
3. String
4. BigInt

These functions

- when called with `new`, return their argument converted to a corresponding wrapper object (`Boolean`, `Number` etc)
- when called without `new`, return their argument converted to a corresponding primitive value (Boolean, Number etc)

These functions are also called implicitly (in the `new` or "constructor" mode) when a primitive is used in the "object" context (e.g. `"foo".length`)