Why is declaring 2 variables with const and comparing them giving me error?
This is my code in TypeScript:
const num1 = 10;
const num2 = 20;

if(num1===num2){
    console.log("true")
}

This is giving me error: 

Error: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '10' and '20' have no overlap.

If i am assigning number to these variables like this:
const num1:number = 10;
const num2:number = 20;

then this is running fine, I am learning typescript, so kindly explain me why is the first code without giving types to variables is giving me error?
Also, if i am declaring variables with let , its running fine.

As the error message says, the types of the variables in the first code are '10' and '20' which can't ever be equal to each other. In the second code you've specified a more broad type for both of them so they can be compared. Remember that individual primitive values can also be types in TS.

But I have assigned both variables as number, typescript should implicitly declare them as numbers without me explicitly giving datatypes. I dont understand, can you please elaborate in detail, I m not so good in this.

No, you have declared them as constants. Their values can ever only be 10 and 20 so their implicit types are '10' and '20'. There would be no point in TS to implicitly type them as numbers because that would be a broader type than what they actually are.

So basically, you are saying that if we assign a variable with const and dont explicitly define a datatype, the value itself is treated as datatype because as const values cannot be changed, they will remain that forever, they cant be overridden so the comparison is useless,am i right?

Yes. That lets Typescript warn about the comparison because it's an obvious error; the condition can never be true so there's no reason for that if statement to be there.

yes i understood, although i did this as experiment: const num1 = 19; const num2 = 20; console.log(typeof num1); console.log(typeof num2); the consoles are printing type as number, why? the type should be the number itself, right? –

typeof prints the Javascript type, not the Typescript type. They're separate concepts. TS types don't exist at runtime anymore.

oh i see, little bit confusing but i got the main point which is the type of const variable is the value itself, thank you so much for the answer.

Typescript often tries to infer the most precise type possible. With a constant you are telling it that this value stays constant and thus the most precise type is the number itself. You can try to change const to var and you will see that Typescript will infer number as to be the most precise type (since it now can be changed to any other number later).
That is also the reason why your comparison shows you this error. Both are constant numbers, with different values. They never can be equal.
You can find another example here: https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/04/28/avoid-inferable/ (you have to scroll down a bit):

TypeScript may infer something more precise than what you expected.
This is generally a good thing. For example:
const axis1: string = 'x';  // Type is string
const axis2 = 'y';  // Type is "y"
"y" is a more precise type for the axis variable, and using it may fix
some errors that would appear with the less-precise string.

If you need a constant to be of a broader type you need to explicitly provide the type.

thank you so much, really helped me, could have upvoted but can't as my reputation is less than 15.

No worries. You should be able to accept it as an answer tho i believe.

yes i understood, although i did this as experiment:
const num1 = 19;
const num2 = 20;
console.log(typeof num1);
console.log(typeof num2);
the consoles are printing type as number, why? the type should be the number itself, right?

You are mixing two concepts here. Your console is logging the runtime type of JavaScript (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67316425/1386873). The type and error in your original question comes from TypeScript, which gets compiled into JavaScript to run.
